# Is there a difference in initializing an int with 001 vs 1?

Tags: c#, integer, literals

I ran across [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) sample on MSDN which uses leading zeros when initializing an int.

```
... new Category(){ Name="Condiments", ID=001}...
```

Is there a difference from just using

```
... new Category(){ Name="Condiments", ID=1}...
```

Comment: For readability maybe. Technically no.

Comment: Which MSDN link exactly?

Comment: Link Added to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no difference.

In many other C-like languages (including C itself), the leading zero would indicate an octal literal.  But not in C#.

Comment: Is this the same for every use? Say for example in a `case` statement? I.e. `case 001` is the same as `case 1`?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, anywhere a numeric value is accepted, the source code `1` or `001` has identical effect.  (oddly enough, in C++ you could run afoul of the One Definition Rule, because the token sequence is not the same)

Answer (score 1):

There is not, 001 is the exact same `int` as 1.